В сколькокомнатной / сколько комнатной квартире
Как правильно?

А Вы, Арина, в сколькокомнатной / сколько комнатной квартире живёте?


Лео-котик, давай сразу писать всё предложение в одно слово, чегоужтамотак?
А-Вы-Арина, в-сколькокомнотноживоквартируетесь?

@Буратино Светский разговор https://vk.com/wall-26694717_7865?z=photo-26694717_457241307%2Fwall-26694717_7866

@Sharon а я вот это про себя прочитал)
Каждый человек имеет право на собственное мнение — при условии, что оно совпадает с нашим.
Джордж Бернард Шоу.
Про кафку долго доходило, потом дошло)

@Буратино  Я просто представила себе заинтересованный разговор молодых людей в наше время (в современный одежде). Говорят они  уже не о Кафке, а о квартирах. Но казусы, вероятно,  тоже возможны, если изысканность молодого человека понимается неправильно)

ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ
         Правильный ли вопрос: Скольки-комнатная квартира?
         Лучший ответ
         Какой чудовищный вопрос!.. .
         Правильно спросить: Сколько комнат в квартире? 

         №253332
         здравствуйте, видимо, мои вопросы прошли мимо вас
         1) можно ли сказать "сколькикомнатная" (о 
         квартире)?
         ОТВЕТ. Это просторечное слово, так говорить не 
         следует.

ОТВЕТ
Все забраковали... Тогда напишем так:
А Вы, Арина, в сколько комнатной квартире живёте?
Пояснение
Красиво!))  И орфографический редактор не подчеркивает  — значит, всё правильно) Авторская орфография  разговорной речи.  Слитно или через дефис  писать нельзя:  таких слов нет в словаре.
Это частный случай, можно сравнить: трех с половиной километровый путь (разрешается правилами,  но тоже выглядит сомнительно, ведь есть трехкилометровый путь). Но кто возьмется доказать, что это не так?)
Или по-английски: And you, Arina, how many rooms do you live in? Тоже эффектно!
